# SEO effect of inline svg

Tags: seo, svg

I wanted to optimize the rendering of our logo which is in svg format. I wanted to try out inlining the svg code of the image on our site's html just so we could eliminate the need of requesting the image resource and so the image immediately renders after the HTML is loaded. My concern is, how would this affect SEO? Since the svg markup would not have any alt attribute or image src.

Comment: Inline images don't get included in image search.   Is image search part of your SEO plan, or are you asking about rankings of the pages that the images are on?

Comment: I guess image search is part of our SEO

Comment: Do people really search your site logo image in Google? That's the main question. Stephen is right Google don't save your SVG **code**, they save images URL. If you place your SVG file somewhere and then reference it with `src="/logo.svg"` tag then Google can save it, otherwise they will not gonna save/index it, hope you understand.

Answer (score 7):

If you are concerned about losing traffic from your logo not appearing in an image search, then I would recommend embedding your image via the `<img>` tag with `alt` text, rather than inline SVG.

---

On the other hand, if your primary concern is traffic coming from a simple web search, the best practice for inline SVG is to format the SVG with the following attributes:

```
<svg role="img" aria-labelledby="title desc">
    <title>...</title>
    <desc>...</desc>
    <!-- Additional SVG Content -->
</svg>
```